# What happens when you compile regular expressions?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

We all know that you can compile your much-used regular expressions into something that performs very good. But what is this witchcraft happening behind the curtains?

I guess that a finite state automaton gets built there, but you must know better than me.

Comment: "a finite state automaton gets built there".  Correct.  What more do you want to know?  It really is just that simple.

Comment: @S.Lott: well, I thought building them was complicated. You could post for instance well known algorithms or something. What would be the modus operandi when someone implements a RE lib?

Comment: Taking capture groups and extended RE capabilities into account, the code generated to implement a regular expression is probably going to be a bit more complex than a finite state automaton.

Comment: Well-known algorithms? Which RE library would you like us to look at for you?  You do have the same access to the source that the rest of us do.  Further, many advanced CS sites have tutorials on RE operations.  I'm unclear what you want to know that you don't already know.  You've described it very completely.

Comment: Moreover, getting into more detail requires abandoning the language-agnostic tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The details of regular expression compilation vary by implementation. For example, compilation in [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile) or [re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/CplusplusAPI#Pre-Compiled_Regular_Expressions) simply creates an instance of a regular expression object. This object's state machine may be modeled as a graph or virtual machine. Without compilation (example: `RE.match(expression, input)`), a new regular expression object is created behind the scenes each time `match` is called. This is needless work if you're going to use an expression more than once.

In C#, one of [three things can happen when you compile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/11/12/256783.aspx):

1. A regular expression object is created (implemented as a virtual machine) similar to Python and re2.
2. A regular expression object is created and its virtual machine opcodes are compiled to in-memory IL instructions on-the-fly.
3. A regular expression object is created and its virtual machine opcodes are compiled to disk as IL instructions.

You mention an interest in algorithms. Take a look at Russ Cox's excellent articles for two approaches:

- [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) - describes a graph-based machine
- [Regular Expression Matching: the Virtual Machine Approach](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp2.html) - describes a virtual machine implementation

Comment: An excellent answer, but I hope that accepting this doesn't discourage others from answering if they have anything cool to share :)

Answer (score 1):

Compiling a regular expression is similar to compiling Java or Python code; the regular expression is converted to an intermediate representation that the RE engine then interprets in order to perform the appropriate operations upon a string.

Comment: This is how you think it must work. However, once upon a time I used to compile regular expressions directly to Z80 machine code - of course, something like that could be done as well today (thereby loosing machine independence, of course)